# How to integrate Django-CMS into an existing project

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I need to integrate Django-CMS 3.x into an existing project (`mypjc` hereafter). I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167313/how-to-start-integrating-django-cms-into-existing-project) question (and other similar) but they point to a [tutorial](http://django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.12/how_to/integrate.html) page that is no longer available.

I'm a bit confused by the tons of infos you can find online and I have not really understood if Django-CMS **can be integrated** as an **app** into an existing and independently running Django project.

`mypjc` (using Django 1.8) would benefit from a user friendly CMS. Basically I'd the user to be able to write texts and to load in their posts images stored in the (common) database, images that are created by the user in `mypjc`.

Is it possible? if yes, could anyone help me defying the steps needed to make the integration clean and successful?

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 3):

With Django CMS, it is indeed possible to integrate it into an existing project.

If you already have an existing project with URL/menu management, then you can simply integrate just the per-page CMS, which can be added as additional field to your model:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # your fields
    my_placeholder = PlaceholderField('placeholder_name')
    # your methods
```

You can find more information [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/placeholders.html).

For any existing projects, you are likely to need to use the manual installation process outlined [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/install.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'd prefer to make a full integration, my goal is to make django-CMS a contrib app in `mypjc`. I followed the manual installation but I get this error `LookupError: Model 'mycustomUser.Profile' not registered.`. `mypjc` uses a custom user model which I linked in the settings.py: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = os.getenv('AUTH_USER_MODEL','mycustomUser..Profile')
`

Comment: Would this help? http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#custom-user-requirements

Comment: Placing the app containing my custom user model before 'cms' in the settings.py apparently solved the issue but a new error pops up: `"your TEMPLATES setting.".format(invalid_backend))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Invalid BACKEND for a template engine: <not defined>. Check your TEMPLATES setting`. Unfortunately the tutorial provided by django-CMS to integrate it into an existing django project is not exausting.