# Adding Django CMS to an existing Django site. Can it damage the existing site and data?

Tags: django, mariadb, django-cms

A friend asked if they could/update their existing site to Django CMS
It has a n e-commerce section added to it and apparently uses the Maris DB.
He wants to use Django CMS mostly to easily add articles and other content.
How intrusive or dangerous is it to install Django CMS to an already existing Django site especially it's customized existing e-commerce section?
Thank you.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022161/how-to-integrate-django-cms-into-an-existing-project

Comment: Thank you Paul but unfortunately the poster didn't seem to get solutions that made it work correctly.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new project and migrating your data. Or take a backup of your project and database, then install Dango CMS. If anything goes wrong, you can always restore your project from the backup.

Comment: I'd see it the other way around, you can convert the present site to an app to be embedded within Django CMS, this works very well in most cases. 
Check out the docs: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html

Comment: @ i.terrible - thank you the django "expert" at the company that does our site says it's impossible. I suppose it would cut into their charge for making any new content of any sort.

Comment: And thank you yo xyres and pauslbeck

Please tell me, you guys are the experts the reason they say it can't be done is said it would interfere with the e-commerce folders section.
The purpose for Django CMS was to create another directory / subdomain just for creating informational content with no need to interact with the e-commerce, if at most add a hyperlink to some products referencing them.
It was still said that it would "break" the e-commerce section which in fact is the only thing on the site. Does this sound right to you ? From my intermediate knowledge of Django  it sounds false.