# How to integrate djangoCMS with existing django project

Tags: django, django-cms

I am new to Django-CMS. I have a Django project with multiple apps to manage specific data. I want to add a CMS platform to my project to let some users contribute to publishing content. The content would be a simple contact page or a complicated page including text, images, as well as charts and report tables of data stored in DB via the existing Django project.

1. I don't have any idea how to add djangoCMS to my existing project (django 3.0).
2. How I can integrate djangoCMS as a new app in my project? Or is it a better idea to have a separate CMS and show data via REST API of the existing project?
3. Can I use Django-CMS plugins to publish my reports via CMS?
4. Is it needed to have a separate database for CMS?

I Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022161/how-to-integrate-django-cms-into-an-existing-project) question, but the final solution was not declared as well as it just addresses my first question. Furthermore, unfortunately, the [tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/install.html) provided by Django-CMS to integrate it into an existing Django project is exhausting.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate Django-CMS into an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022161/how-to-integrate-django-cms-into-an-existing-project)

Comment: @wfehr I checked it but it didn't help with my question.